# Download file with Selenium and Firefox

Tags: python, selenium

I try to download pdf file from something i click on a website but i can't find a way to download it ... I know that doesn't come from my next request but it's just a question of setting...

Here is my code

```
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/pdf")
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir","mydirectory")
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled",True)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you see and error?

Comment: Does that mean when you click, it's getting downloaded ? But you can't seem to find where it is in your local machine ?

Comment: @Prophet i don't see any error i click exactly were it supposed to download but nothing append ...

Comment: Also no pop-up dialog etc. presented? Just nothing?

Comment: @cruisepandey i don't know if it's get downloaded because i can't find any folder were the file is download ...

Comment: @Prophet i see in the windows handle that a windows is open very quickly : so i assumed that what i try to do works fine , just the downloading part don't works x)

Comment: @NonaryAce : Which OS you are on ? and Do you know file name in advance

Comment: @NonaryAce what was it, tell us, it's interesting!

Comment: You even can answer your own question and we maybe will upvote it :)

Comment: @Prophet ok i will do this ;)

Comment: Please ping me when you did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to check the default download folder which is download ;)

Comment: That's what caused the problem?